# Replace switch with a better pattern (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have to upgrade my app to display pages based on a users type and role properties. Currently I employ a simple switch statement to do this based on user type, e.g.

```
switch(type) {
  case 'a':
    return CONSTANT.ONE;

  case 'b':
    return CONSTANT.TWO;

  default:
    return null;
}
```

The switch just returns a constant string which dictates the view showm, but that isn't scalable as number of types , roles increases.  Can anyone suggest a good pattern to use in this case. I thought a state pattern might be good but is that over the top just to return a string ?

Thanks

Comment: This probably should be on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: you could keep it in an array, indexed by your current `case` value

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - This is example code, and as such, would not be appropriate on Code Review.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek No, it should not. Example code is off-topic on Code Review.

Answer (score 3):

Very similarly to @MarkusJarderot, but with a few important differences in behavior, I would use:

```
var mapping = {
    'a': CONSTANT.ONE,
    'b': CONSTANT.TWO,
    '_default': null
};

return mapping.hasOwnProperty(type) ? mapping[type] : mapping["_default"];
```

When the value of `mapping[type]` is falsy, this will still return it, rather than going to the `null` alternative. That will be very helpful when one of your values is `0` or an empty string.

Comment: The 'hasOwnProperty' check is also important to prevent inherited proprieties from being returned. (E.g. If `type` is "toString")

Comment: Today, this can be replaced by `mapping[type] ?? mapping._default`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an object as a lookup:

```
var roles = {};
```

Then you can add roles like this:

```
roles['a']=CONSTANT.ONE;
```

and look them up like this:

```
var xxx = roles['a'];
```

This way you can add things to the roles in different places in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use Strategy Pattern:

```
//Example without strategy pattern
gameDifficulty(difficulty) {
  switch(difficulty){
    case 'easy':
      easyGameMode();
      break;
    case 'difficult'
      difficultMode();
      break;
  }
}

// Using Strategy
const strategies = {
  easy: easyGameMode(),
  difficult: difficultGameMode(),
  //More strategies
  __default__: normalGameMode()
}

const easyGameMode = (game) => {
  game.difficulty(1);
  //Do easy game mode stuff in here
  return game;
}

const normalGameMode= (game) => {
  game.difficulty(2);
  //Do normal game mode stuff in here
  return game;
}

const difficultGameMode = (game) => {
  game.difficulty(3);
  //Do difficult game mode stuff in here
  return game;
}

const startGame = (game, difficulty) => {
  const gameModifier = strategies[difficulty] ?? strategies.__default__;
  return gameModifier(game, difficulty);
}
```

More info in this [article](https://dev.to/wecarrasco/strategy-pattern-with-javascript-dha).